# One button two listeners in java

Tags: java, android

im trying to setup two listeners for one button. Here is my code:
This is the main code

```
            public class LoggingEventsActivity extends Activity  implements OnClickListener {
                /** Called when the activity is first created. */
                @Override
                public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.main);

                    temp obj = new temp(R.id.button1,this);

                    View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.button1);
                    continueButton.setOnClickListener(this);
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    final TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    t.setText("hello world");

                }
            }
```

This is a class which i create an object in the main code :

```
            public class temp extends Activity implements OnClickListener{


                public temp(int id, LoggingEventsActivity  ref){
                    try{

                    View continueButton = findViewById(id);
                    continueButton.setOnClickListener(ref);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    final TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    t.append("extra");
                }  

            }
```

I keep getting a null pointer exception here is the logcat dump:

```
            11-15 11:08:29.589: W/System.err(24268): java.lang.NullPointerException
            11-15 11:08:29.605: W/System.err(24268):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
            11-15 11:08:29.616: W/System.err(24268):    at events.log.temp.<init>(temp.java:15)
            11-15 11:08:29.635: W/System.err(24268):    at events.log.LoggingEventsActivity.onCreate(LoggingEventsActivity.java:17)
            11-15 11:08:29.655: W/System.err(24268):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            11-15 11:08:29.664: W/System.err(24268):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            11-15 11:08:29.675: W/System.err(24268):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
            11-15 11:08:29.685: W/System.err(24268):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
            11-15 11:08:29.696: W/System.err(24268):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
            11-15 11:08:29.704: W/System.err(24268):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
            11-15 11:08:29.715: W/System.err(24268):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            11-15 11:08:29.725: W/System.err(24268):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            11-15 11:08:29.735: W/System.err(24268):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
            11-15 11:08:29.744: W/System.err(24268):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            11-15 11:08:29.766: W/System.err(24268):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            11-15 11:08:29.784: W/System.err(24268):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            11-15 11:08:29.784: W/System.err(24268):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            11-15 11:08:29.795: W/System.err(24268):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
            11-15 11:08:37.355: D/gralloc_goldfish(24268): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
            11-15 11:09:34.365: D/dalvikvm(24268): Debugger has detached; object registry had 441 entries
            11-15 11:14:20.436: W/System.err(24548): java.lang.NullPointerException
            11-15 11:14:20.445: W/System.err(24548):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1794)
            11-15 11:14:20.445: W/System.err(24548):    at events.log.temp.<init>(temp.java:15)
            11-15 11:14:20.445: W/System.err(24548):    at events.log.LoggingEventsActivity.onCreate(LoggingEventsActivity.java:17)
            11-15 11:14:20.455: W/System.err(24548):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
            11-15 11:14:20.455: W/System.err(24548):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
            11-15 11:14:20.455: W/System.err(24548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1919)
            11-15 11:14:20.455: W/System.err(24548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1980)
            11-15 11:14:20.455: W/System.err(24548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:122)
            11-15 11:14:20.455: W/System.err(24548):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1146)
            11-15 11:14:20.455: W/System.err(24548):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            11-15 11:14:20.465: W/System.err(24548):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            11-15 11:14:20.465: W/System.err(24548):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
            11-15 11:14:20.465: W/System.err(24548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            11-15 11:14:20.475: W/System.err(24548):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            11-15 11:14:20.475: W/System.err(24548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
            11-15 11:14:20.475: W/System.err(24548):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
            11-15 11:14:20.475: W/System.err(24548):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: why would you need 2 listeners for 1 button?

Comment: @lc2817 one listener will log the end and the other will perform the action. I dont want to combine them into one since i would like to keep the code of logging seperate from the code of the action

Comment: @hovanessyan one listener will log the end and the other will perform the action. I dont want to combine them into one since i would like to keep the code of logging seperate from the code of the action

Comment: Obligatory reference to obscene internet video.

Comment: Then why don't you chain the listeners transmitting events?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the `CompositeListener` pattern. I use it all the time, because I want to **separate concerns**, and keep my listeners in external classes, not anonymous.

The idea is basically to have a **unique listener** that delegates all its `onClick` calls to all the listeners you want, which it references. The beautiful thing is that you can apply that pattern to any sort of listener (even your custom ones).

(The following is quickly coded from memory in the SO editor, it may contain syntax error, but will give you an idea)

```
public class CompositeOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {
    private final Set<OnClickListener> delegates = new HashSet<OnClickListener>();

    public CompositeOnClickListener(OnClickListener... listeners) {
        for (OnClickListener listener : listeners) {
            delegates.add(listener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (OnClickListener listener : delegates) {
            listener.onClick(v);
        }
    } 
}
```

You create one of these and feed it all the listeners you want to pass to your button (including your logging listener:

```
OnClickListener myListener = new CompositeOnClickListener(listener1, listener2, listener3);
```

And you add it to your button:

```
Button continueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
continueButton.setOnClickListener(myListener);
```

Comment: Hello Thanks for the answer. But this requires to change every code segments that creates listeners i would like to add some external code and would like to keep the application source code modifications to a minimal. Basically i want to if possible completely seperate the logging code from the application source. Thanks

Comment: Are you saying you want to keep the "Main" code unchanged, and only extend it? It's still possible to do the CompositeListener with minimal change: your "temp" class becomes the CompositeListener, keeps an internal set of listeners, and in its onClick method,  iterates over them all and call their onClick methods...

Comment: yes preferably i would like to keep code unchanged. Can you please post a new answer so i can try both ways and see which one works better. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**you can't instanciate** an `Activity` with new, you should use `startActivity(Intent intent);` to launch an activity , and the second thing , is that you should declare it on your manifest file like this : `<activity android:name="TempActivity" />`

NB : in your activity `TempActivity` , you should override the method `onCreate()` to init your Views etc...

Comment: i dont want to create a new activity i just want to create a listener so i can log the button events from the main activity

Comment: so why did you create the class temp ? , if you want to give the button two statements to execute, one listener is enough , and then use a boolean to switch between the two statements

Comment: @MikeG This is also the cause of the null pointer. You are trying to find a view by id in a different activity than the activity which contains the button.

Comment: yes ,that's it Jim  , because in his second Activity  ( temp ) , there is no setContentView, so when he is trying to findViewById , it returns null and the app crash

Answer (score 1):

Ok one possible sollution would be that on button click to create 2 different threads and let each thread do one of the actions.

Second possible sollution is create the so called Logger class with main method and and implement it on some port of your computer,so when somone clicks the button the class is called through a socket.You can make it open along with a program by using few lines of code

Third possible solution is to create RMI class that will do the logging and send back the result that will be written to a file

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply, thats exactly what i am looking for. Can you please edit your answer and include more detail on how to use the second solution. Including code would be much appreciated since i am new to android dev and java. Thanks!

Comment: These solutions are far too complicated for what you want to accomplish. Multithreading? Socket? RMI? Just to add logging to a button?

Comment: @Guillaume i would like to expand this to more controls down the road not only buttons. what do you mean by add logging to a button? how does that work? and can it be extended to other controls ? Thanks

Comment: You're the one saying you want to add logging to a button in a  comment above: "one listener will log the end and the other will perform the action". I just said using multithreading, RMI or sockets are quite complex and involved solutions, probably more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: For second sollution there is actually way to much data to be written here but here are some links:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html
http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~cs379/DistributedSystems/rmi_tut.html

Comment: @user1021229 the second solution is using a socket no rmi. please provide more info on the socket so i can mark your reply as an answer :) thank-you